# How to use TV-tuner?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, tv-tuner

I have a TV-tuner of Zebronics Model No. ZEB-TU 1000. In its packet it has only Windows support. When typing `lsusb` I can only find `Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1b71:0042`. What should I do?

Does the model I mentioned above is supported by linux?

Comment: Try installing **Kaffeine**, from *Software Centre*. Also checkout: http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap

Comment: I have tried kaffeine.But can't use it for my tv tuner

Comment: **What is your specific problem?** See also: http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Stk1160_based_USB_2.0_video_and_audio_capture_devices

Comment: When I type lsusb it not showing my tv tuner.It only shows Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1b71:0042.Does the model I mentioned above is supported by linux?

Comment: I think this link may work for me:https://github.com/mwelchuk/usbtv. But while installing it says following error "Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.13.0-43-generic KVERSION=3.13.0-43-generic KERNELDIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for usbtv: 1.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-43-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/usbtv/1.0/build/make.log for more information.
"

Comment: Please help me and discuss about it david6