# How to use Zebronics TV Tuner in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, tv-tuner

I have recently installed Ubuntu. How can I use my TV tuner to watch cable tv? The TV tuner model number is Zebronics TU1000.

There is a driver cd for this which works on Windows 7. Can I use this cd for Ubuntu also? I have found some question about [How to use TV-tuner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567621/how-to-use-tv-tuner) but I do not find any solution. I am very new to ubuntu.

Comment: Please edit into the question results of `grep -i dvb /var/log/messages`

Comment: How can I do that?Would I run the comment in terminal?

Comment: yes it will show if the card is recognized.

Comment: No such file or directory.it is showing this

Comment: try typing `sudo`[space] before the command in the upvoted comment.

Comment: It's showing the same "No such file or directory".I think the card is can capture NTSC, PAL, Secam.Here is the link http://zebronics.com/products/external/zeb-tu1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried hard to work this TV-tuner with Ubuntu but with no luck.As working with a unsupported hardware in Linux is very difficult.So to use this TV-tuner you should have dual boot with Windows.But if I ever found a work-around I'll let you know.

Comment: Can you suggest some TV-tuner which can work with Ubuntu?

Comment: No I can't.As I am using the same tuner with dual boot.